# Correct usage of article tags for minor blocks of text

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and have store hours next to a google maps, and above those two the items that the address but was wondering what was the correct semantic tag to put next to some of the tags.

a) the address

and

b) the hours

I was thinking of putting the article tag next to the maps and hours since it is independent on its own, and same with the address, but then I read somewhere in HTML5 site that it should "self-contained/distributable". Both seem kind of insignificant on their own (not a news article in itself).

I'm thinking either:

a) both divs,

b) both articles,

c) one div for the address, one article for hours (b/c address seems minor, no title, whereas hours has title, feels more substantive)

d) one combined article that surrounds both elements, with divs for styling?

**Format**:

Line 1: image

Line 2: address (We are located in the Yorkdale Shopping Centre. Our address is: 3100 Dufferin St. Toronto, Ontario, M4W 3L8)

Line 3: google maps + hours(Our Hours:
Monday: 10am - 7pm 
Tuesday: 10am - 7pm 
Wednesday: 10am - 7pm 
Thursday: 10am - 8pm 
Friday: 10am - 8pm 
Saturday: 10am - 7pm 
Sunday: 12am - 6pm)

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/yuyuwis/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but I can say that the way I've seen the article tag being used is with blocks of text, like a text-post of some kind ex. a comment.

The address-part looks good, just a `<div>` and the use the `<span>` to style individual parts.

I would do something like this for the opening-hours since it's technically a timetable therefore it would be logical to use a table.

```
<div class = "timetable">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Monday</td>
           <td>7-12</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Tuesday</td>
           <td>8-11</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

I would not use the article tag in this case simply because it doesn't really make sense.